# Ionic 3 height problems

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, responsive-design

I am facing problems in Ionic 3 background height - if I set `height 100vh` this happens :

[image]

**How to set background height to always have all background (seen and scrolled) be colored - not white ?**

**Height 100% - is also bad. for a smaller devices**

Comment: If you are setting the height and background color of a component, try also setting `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: Try using background-size: auto 80%; for assuming red container height is 20%, or     background-size: auto 200px; assuming red container height 200px;

Answer (score 0):

in your app.css copy this:

```
ion-content {
background-image: url("the url of your image background");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

}`